# How to use .htaccess to cache data?

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching

I am a beginner in web development and I wanted to know how to cache data using the .htaccess file in a browser. I wanted to know if it is possible to make the site load offline but also show updated content when online without having to hit reload (my website is under 1mb: www.windowstaan.pe.hu ).

I managed to get it to load offline using this code:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ## <IfModule mod_expires.c> ExpiresActive On ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year" ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year" ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year" ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 day" ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 day" ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month" ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month" ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month" ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year" ExpiresDefault "access 1 month" </IfModule> ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But the problem is any changes i make in my html and css files dont show up even after a day has passed , the only way to make them show up is load the website and hit the reload button. However this is problematic since my website is mainly used inside a browser app which doesnt have a reload button.

So i decided to remove the html and css lines fully in hopes of making it cache only the images so that my changes will show up fast without the need of loading images , However all browsers including chrome are able to open my site even after i put the device offline. It is almost like it saves a screenshot of the website.

Please recommend me on how i can get the most speed out of the site while also being able to update it.

Comment: Look this http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html#Caching_mod_headers

Comment: Or this: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html#Caching_mod_expires